# Mail sending fails without errors

Tags: laravel-5.5, mailgun

**What do I have:**

1. Laravel app (5.5.45)
2. Mailgun

I send mail like this:

```
//App\Listeners namespace
Mail::to($event->user)->send(new Report($event->report));
```

There are no errors in app logs. And there are no incoming mail in the Mailgun dashboard. And, obviously, no mail on my mailbox (spam too).

I'm using [debug bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), and when email sending is triggered, my mail appears in the debug bar.

**What have I tried:**

1. `composer update`
2. Delete Mailgun domain and create a new one
3. `php artisan config:cache`
4. Use Mailgun sandbox domain
5. Serve my Laravel app via HTTPS and HTTP

Nothing helped.

**Question:** how can I debug mail senging in other ways? I know about Mailgun webhooks, but I can set up a webhook for my local app.

P. S. When I'm sending mail using `curl`, everything is ok. So, I can say that my api keys are ok.

**Edit 1:**

```
dd(Mail::to(...));
```

returns `null`.

**Edit 2:** everything is ok when sending via SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

From Laravel 5.3V Notify system feature is introduced try this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications

Comment: Sorry, I don't need Notifications. I used to use Mail, now it stopped to work as expected. Just trying to fix that was working before.

Comment: In Notify system you can send email also